# Apache redirecting to HTTP for subdomains after adding trailing slash

Tags: apache-2.4, configuration

I edited the question based on new information.

I know I am a big novice for server configuration stuff.

What I noticed is that mod_dir adds backslash properly in all non-subdomain paths.

For example: `https://example.co/test => https://example.co/test/`

But when I have a subdomain: `https://sub.example.co/test => http://sub.example:443/test/`

[image]

Here is my **default-ssl**

```
 ExpiresActive On
 ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
 Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
 Alias "/library/" "/var/www/html/example/library/"
 <Directory /var/www/html/>
  Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
 </Directory>
 <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
  SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
 </FilesMatch>
 <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
  SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
 </Directory>
 <VirtualHost _default_:443>
  ServerName example.co
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example
  SSLEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co/privkey.pem
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co/chain.pem
 </VirtualHost>
 <VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAlias sub.*
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/sub
 </VirtualHost>
```

Here is my **000-default**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>
```

Why do my subdomains throw errors and change into HTTP when mod_dir adds directory slashes?

Comment: `SetHandler some-handler` - You didn't _literally_ use that "example" as-is did you? `DirectorySlash On` is the default - so unless you have explicitly disabled this elsewhere in your server config then that is not the issue. You've not included your vHost config for port 80? You have a bunch of directives in a _server_ context followed by a minimal vHost for 443? mod_rewrite directives in a _server_ context are not inherited by the vHost by default anyway. _Wild guess_ is that your HTTP (port 80) `ServerName` is set (or resolving) incorrectly - perhaps as a result of misconfigured vhosts?

Comment: Those `ErrorDocument` directives are certainly "look wrong" - why would you "redirect" to the document root (these are also missing a trailing slash)? These would only "mask" an underlying error (without looking at your server's error log).

Comment: @MrWhite I apologize for my novice-ness in Apache server configurations. I edited the question. I found out that this issue only exists with my virtual hosts (subdomains).